# How to implement "type is <typeName> table of rowid index by" concept in postgresql to compare table data with new inserted data

Tags: postgresql, oracle, plsql, triggers, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to convert below piece of code from oracle to postgres(Basically the goal is to insert some records in table based on some date without overlapping and if there is date range overlapping it should raise trigger.) But after lot of efforts unable to get clue how to do it?

```sql
DECLARE
    V_check PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_check
    FROM   user_objects
    WHERE  object_name = 'STORE_ROWID'
    AND    object_type = 'PACKAGE';
    IF V_check=0 THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE PACKAGE store_rowid AS'
        ||CHR(10)||'  TYPE T_rowid IS TABLE OF ROWID INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;'
        ||CHR(10)||'  T_newones    T_rowid;'
        ||CHR(10)||'  T_empty      T_rowid;'
        ||CHR(10)||'END store_rowid;';
    END IF;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER biu_base_host
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON BASE_HOST
    BEGIN
        STORE_ROWID.T_newones := STORE_ROWID.T_empty;
END biu_base_host;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER aiufr_base_host
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON BASE_HOST
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        STORE_ROWID.T_newones(STORE_ROWID.T_newones.COUNT+1) := :NEW.ROWID;
END aiufr_base_host;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER aiu_base_host
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON BASE_HOST
    DECLARE
        r           BASE_HOST%ROWTYPE;
        V_count     INTEGER;
        V_status    PLS_INTEGER;
        C_lockid    CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 1001;

    BEGIN
    V_status := DBMS_LOCK.request(C_lockid,DBMS_LOCK.x_mode,release_on_commit=>TRUE);
    IF V_status NOT IN (0,4)
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20102,'DBMS_LOCK.request ERROR, rc='||V_status);
    END IF;

    FOR i IN 1..STORE_ROWID.T_newones.COUNT
    LOOP
        SELECT  * INTO r
        FROM    BASE_HOST
        WHERE   ROWID = STORE_ROWID.T_newones(i);

        SELECT  COUNT(*) INTO V_count
        FROM    BASE_HOST
        WHERE   ROWID <> STORE_ROWID.T_newones(i)
        AND     ZONE_ID = r.ZONE_ID
        AND     SITE_ID = r.SITE_ID
        AND     ORG_ID = r.ORG_ID
        AND     (start_date BETWEEN r.start_date AND r.end_date
                OR end_date BETWEEN r.start_date AND r.end_date
                OR (start_date < r.start_date AND end_date > r.end_date));

        IF V_count <> 0 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,
                'Range from '||
                TO_CHAR(r.start_date,'YYYYMMDD-HH24MISS') ||
                ' to '||
                TO_CHAR(r.end_date,'YYYYMMDD-HH24MISS')||
                ' overlaps existing records');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END aiu_base_host;
```

Comment: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  if you migrate an existing project today, don't start with a completely outdated Postgres version. You should go straight for Postgres 13

Comment: In Postgres you can define an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) to prevent overlapping ranges. No need for a trigger or PL/pgSQL

Comment: Take a look at [Migrate your mindset](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/). While it uses SQL Server to Postgres it equally applies converting form Oracle. You need to determine the purpose of a code/user types before converting. Also this is either very old or just poor Oracle, a single compound trigger would do the same. But forget about a direct translation. Postgres does not have Packages, does not have collections, and does not have rowid. I repeat the suggestion by @a_horse_with_no_name, define an **exclusion constraint** and get rid of all that code. And Upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, exclusion constraint I suppose is perfect way to achieve this and I have written below code to achieve the same functionality:                                                              CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
   
create table base_host(
 zone_id numeric(3),
 site_id numeric(3),
 org_id VARCHAR(16),
 start_date date,
 end_date date,
 reserved_capacity numeric(5,2),
 last_update date,
 user_id VARCHAR(32),
 EXCLUDE USING GIST (zone_id WITH =,site_id WITH =,org_id WITH =,daterange("start_date", "end_date") WITH &&));

Comment: You should ask @a_horse_with_no_name to re-post their post as an answer then accept it, and or post your solution as an answer and then accept it. Answered questions help later questioners with the same issue. Please don not just leave an answered question in an unanswered state.

Answer (score 0):

exclusion constraint I suppose is perfect way to achieve this and I have written below code to achieve the same functionality:

CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
create table base_host( zone_id numeric(3), site_id numeric(3), org_id VARCHAR(16), start_date date, end_date date, reserved_capacity numeric(5,2), last_update date, user_id VARCHAR(32), EXCLUDE USING GIST (zone_id WITH =,site_id WITH =,org_id WITH =,daterange("start_date", "end_date") WITH &&));